# Web page is refressing again and again

Tags: html, web-services, google-cloud-storage, web-hosting

I have google cloud storage hosting. I have made changes to google search console to where I have verified my domain name with www and without www so that my website will be available to access trough both. I have also tried to put redirect code in .htaccess file in cloud storage. After this changes when I am reloading my website it is automatically refreshing it self again and again?

Code written in .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^turtlelabs\.co.in\
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.turtlelabs.co.in\ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^turtlelabs.co.in\ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}\$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.turtlelabs.co.in/">